# Easiest way to add references in TeXnicCenter

Tags: biblatex, citing, texniccenter

i am currently working on a file where i just want to use the easiest possible way to add citations.
I tried using biblatex as explained here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_biblatex

However, the minimal working example does not show any references:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I made a plain text-file i named sample.bib containing wich is in the same folder as the .tex file:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = "1973",
    chapter = "1.2",
    keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
...
```

however, there is literally no blibliography/reference list printed. Can someone help me?

Comment: you need to run biber to generate the refences so pdflatex, biber pdflatex

Comment: I made a tutorial some years ago that should still be correct: https://youtu.be/ZYvS52511oQ

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments, i eventually went back to JabRef and somehow solved my issue, but it was still not the optimal solution. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: From the description of the problem so far I'd say the most likely source of the problem is that you did not run Biber on your document. In order to produce citations and the bibliography you need to run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX on your file (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX; in your case most likely pdfLaTeX). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can make your editor run Biber for you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what Biber does.

Comment: Thanks moewe, appreciating your help.

Comment: Make sure that BibTeX and MakeIndex are selected under the Project->Properties menu.